# Style Cop rules don't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, stylecop

I added Parent Settings File to the solutions folder. After that I unchecked there rule SA1101 in the parent file. Also I set "Do not merge with any file" in parent file, and set merge in the parent file in the project`s settings file.

But after I build project I get this error. I attached window with error and settings winwows - there are no overloads or something like this.

[image: Error with settings window]

I really don`t now what I can do, to resolve this issue....

ADDED.

But in resharper all rules work normal. But when I try to build solutions - my settings are ignored.
I used StyleCop Version 4.5.24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Style Cope For Resharper. I tested the same solutions on another PC and all works fine